# How to search an element in array using node.js in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In mongodb there is a document like below,

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("57443657ee5b5ccc30c4e6f8"),
   "name": "Kevin",
   "email": "kevinwarn@gmail.com",
   "password": "$2a$13$iZ0PhuY6VlBF6qC9rUredrG39Fw5pEKkIh.VCLiGsLPZMKYveyzey",
   "mobile": "9980896745",
   "__v": NumberInt(0),
   "ocassionTypes": [
     {
       "occasiontype": "Anniversary",
       "date": "2016-05-30T18:30:00.000Z" 
    },
     {
       "occasiontype": "Donation",
       "date": "2016-07-24T18:30:00.000Z" 
    },
     {
       "occasiontype": "House Warming",
       "date": "2016-09-21T18:30:00.000Z" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

So I have written a query in **Nodejs** to search `occasiontype` element in `ocassionTypes` array like below,

```
router.post('/find-registry', function(req, res){
    var uEmail = req.body.email;
    var uocType = req.body.userOccasion;
    var findUserId = function(db, callback) {
        
            var cursor =db.collection('users').find({email:uEmail, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType}}}).toArray(function(err, docs1){
                if(err){  
                    callback(new Error("Some problem"));
                } else {
                    callback(null,docs1);
                } 
            });
    };
        
    MongoClient.connect(config.database, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        findUserId(db, function(err,docs1) {
            db.close();
            if(err) return res.json({result:null})
            else
            return res.json({result1:docs1});
        });
    });                     
});
```

Using this query I am getting 0th index element, but if I give 1st and 2nd element it always shows only 0th index in the output.

In front end I have given input as shown in the picture below.

### file.html

[image: front end image]

Is there any wrong in my query? please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query is right but it will give matched document with full array

just add projection in your query

```
db.collection('users').find({email:uEmail, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType}}},{email:1, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType}}})
```

Comment: Its worked now. But it not working when the ocassionTypes array contains only one element like { "_id": ObjectId("56fe44836ce2226431f5388f"), "name": "Hemanth", "email": "hemanth@gmail.com", "password": "$2a$10$QeI.ntMGHF0jjAtWh/bBDu.RnZO7t5BUmVQJ.r7FxGdFM2.5.7erS", "__v": NumberInt(0), "mobile": "9989786745", "ocassionTypes": [ { "occasiontype": "Birthday", "date": "2016-04-17T18:30:00.0Z" } ] }

Comment: i check it ,it working me . when one element in array

Comment: Actually i have added one more condition to query. Now my query is as shown below   `var cursor =db.collection('users').find({email:uEmail, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType, date:oDate}}}, {name: 1, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype: uocType, date:oDate}}}).toArray(function(err, docs1){
     if(err){  
      callback(new Error("Some problem"));
     } else {
      callback(null,docs1);
     } 
    });`

Comment: i think i dint see any extra condition in yours , pls mention ur extra condtion

Comment: ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType, **date:oDate**}}}, {name: 1, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype: uocType, date:oDate}}}

Comment: i think date field didnt match , becoz date field contain date and time . time is mismatch so only it return empty

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching in sub document, mongodb returns all sub-document instead of matched sub-document. You can limit no. of sub-document using following code.

```
var cursor =db.collection('users').find({email:uEmail, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype:uocType}}},{email: 1, ocassionTypes: {$elemMatch: {occasiontype: uocType}}}).toArray(function(err, docs1){
                if(err){  
                    callback(new Error("Some problem"));
                } else {
                    callback(null,docs1);
                } 
            });
```

It is not tested but it should work.

Comment: Its worked now. But it not working when the `ocassionTypes` array contains only one element like  `{
   "_id": ObjectId("56fe44836ce2226431f5388f"),
   "name": "Hemanth",
   "email": "hemanth@gmail.com",
   "password": "$2a$10$QeI.ntMGHF0jjAtWh/bBDu.RnZO7t5BUmVQJ.r7FxGdFM2.5.7erS",
   "__v": NumberInt(0),
   "mobile": "9989786745",
   "ocassionTypes": [
     {
       "occasiontype": "Birthday",
       "date": "2016-04-17T18:30:00.0Z" 
    } 
  ] 
}
`